# Prove that $k h = h k$ for $h \in H $ & $k \in K $

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

I found the following statement in my lecture but I don't see exactly why it is true

> We have $G $ a group and are given $H$ , $K$ two normal subgroups of $G$ such that :$\; H\cap{} K = \left\{e \right\}$
>
> Then for all $\; h \in H $ and for all $\; k \in K$ we have :
>
> $$hk=kh$$

Thanks in advance for your help .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since both $H,K$ are normal subgroups, $$hkh^{-1}k^{-1} = h(kh^{-1}k^{-1}) \in H \\ hkh^{-1}k^{-1} = (hkh^{-1})k^{-1} \in K$$
Therefore $$hkh^{-1}k^{-1} \in H\cap K = \{e\},$$
so $hkh^{-1}k^{-1} = e$ or $hk=kh$.

Answer (score 0):

We have $k^hk^{-1}=hkh^{-1}k^{-1}=h(h^{-1})^k$ in both $H$ and $K$ by normality.

Comment: Thanks Shaun , just to know how did you put the yellow background for my statement

Comment: Hi @SkyLand77. You're welcome! To highlight a sentence or paragraph like I did, one starts it with the symbol >.